# Freshly installed redis not responding?

Tags: ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-11.10

I had to install a very old redis-server on a very old Ubuntu server and used the package manager for it. However, after installing and starting the server, I do not get any response but timeouts.

`redis-cli ping`: Timeout

The log only shows this:

```
[27714] 25 Jul 13:27:59 * Server started, Redis version 2.2.11
[27714] 25 Jul 13:27:59 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
[27714] 25 Jul 13:27:59 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong here?

Comment: Somebody forgot to upgrade the server from 12.04 to a newer version?

Comment: Almost :) See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be `lo` not getting up after a dist-upgrade and restart. All I had to do is `ifconfig lo up`